# how can I find the average length of inputed lists/names from a user

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

```
def myNames():

    b = []
    while True:
      a = input("Enter Name: ")
      if a != "done":
        b.append(a)
      elif a == "done":
       break
myNames()

def all_lengths(myNames):
  all_lengths = []
  num_of_strings = len(myNames)

  for item in myNames:
     string_size = len(item)
     all_lengths.append(string_size)
     total_size = sum(all_lengths)
  ave_size = float(total_size) / float(num_of_strings)
  print (ave_size)
all_lengths(myNames)
```

I am trying to find how I can find the average length of lists/names inputed by a user for ex: john, sam, Samantha. (all inputed from a user) and it should give me the average length (in numbers) for how much letters there are in the names

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    all_lengths(myNames)
  File "main.py", line 15, in all_lengths
    num_of_strings = len(myNames)
TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len()
```

that is the error I keep getting

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use [`statistics.mean()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean)? Also, what does your current code do versus what you expect it to?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: it just gives me a bunch of errors and saying there is no function. and no I have to use functions and lists. and I don't know what statistics.mean() does

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: you passing the function not calling it, you forgot the brackets: all_lengths(myNames())

Comment: @Kian if you read the documentation I linked, you'd have seen that `statistics.mean()` returns the average of a list of values. So in other words, you just pass it a list of string lengths for example, and it'll return the average length.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function expecting the result to be a part of the function. This is not how python works. You should return the result:

```py
def myNames():
    b = []
    while True:
        a = input("Enter Name: ")
        if a != "done":
            b.append(a)
        else:
            return b

def all_lengths(myNames):
  num_of_strings = len(myNames)
  total_size = 0
  for item in myNames:
     total_size += len(item)
  ave_size = float(total_size) / float(num_of_strings)
  print(ave_size)

all_lengths(myNames())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the function not its result, you forgot the brackets: `all_lengths(myNames())`